# How to Get Rid Off 'index.php' in URI Using Virtual Host and .htaccess File?

Tags: virtualhost, .htaccess, apache-2.4, alias

I am using a Virtual Host for my Laravel 4 Project on my local host to get rid off typing ***'localhost/L4/public/index.php/route'***. Laravel also uses a **.htaccess** file in it's public directory. Both the **Virtual Host** and **.htaccess** files are given below:

**Virtual Host File**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@mail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/L4/public

    ServerName www.L4.dev

    Alias /billing /var/www/L5/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/L4/public/>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**.htaccess File for Laravel 4 Project**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Suppose Laravel 4 project has a route **'route1'**. This **Virtual Host** file and **.htaccess** file let me allow to access my Laravel 4 project's **'route1'** using **"www.L4.dev/index.php/route1"**.

I added the following in my Virtual Host file to get rid off '**index.php**' from the above given address:

```
<Directory /var/www/L4/public/>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

This works fine and now I can access the my '**route1**' route of **Laravel 4 project** using '**www.L4.dev/route1**'.

**But notice** I'm also using an **Alias *'/billing'*** in my **Virtual Host** file to access another **project L5** (laravel 5 project).

Now suppose this **Laravel 5 project** has a route '**route2**' and to access this route I've to type *'**www.L4.dev/billing/index.php/route2**'*.

I also want to get rid off '**index.php**' from here as well but don't know how to do so???

I'm sure that I've to do some thing with this **Virtual Host** file and with the **.htaccess** file in '**pbulic**' directory of L5 but don't know what and how to do?

**Note:** There is no Virtual Host file for Laravel 5 project, just Alias is getting used to access it.

**.htacess file in 'L5/Public/' Directory**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Can some one pleas help me in this regard ????

Comment: I edited my answer to be easier

Comment: Don't forget that you have to edit your links. Remove `index.php` from every link.

Answer (score 0):

Change your main .htaccess like that and remove the other:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Billing
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^/billing/(.*) /billing/index.php/$1 [L]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Or you can use this trick:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(/billing/|)(.*) $1index.php$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I've added this before Front Controller, but then my Alias **/billing** doesn't work and treated as the **route** of **laravel 4 project**. i.e.

`www.L4.dev/billing/route2'

In the above URI, **/billing** is treated as **route** of Laravel 4.2 not as an Alias.

Comment: You have to add the rules i wrote in .htaccess File for Laravel 4 Project and then remove L5/Public/ which is useless

Comment: this works only for the '/' route. Don't works with any other route except '/'. I mean to say that when I access **www.L4.dev/billing** it is same as **www.L4.dev/billing/index.php** this works. It's a good progress for me. But when I access the equallent of  **www.L4.dev/billing/index.php/route2** which is  **www.L4.dev/billing/route2**, it doesn't work and gives me the error ** The requested URL /billing/route2 was not found on this server.**

Comment: what is the result of acces to www.L4.dev/billing/index.php/route2 ?

Comment: It works fine. but if I remove **index.php** and just use **www.L4.dev/billing/index.php/route2** it gives the error **The requested URL /billing/route2 was not found on this server.**

Comment: I updated the answer

Comment: Same error **Not Found  The requested URL /billing/route2 was not found on this server.**